# Drawing a Single Google Line Chart with multiple lines using JSON

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw a line chart from data received from  mysql database. From the database I have these data

[image]

I want to draw a google line chart getting the x-axis as the sales date and the y-axis as the product_name. But I want multiple lines for each product, like this.

[image]

I can draw the chart for a single product. But can't imagine how to do it for multiple products in the same chart. I'm using JSON to get data for the chart and using a MySQL database. Any help, tutorial would be appreciated. Thanks.

PS: I followed this tutorial for a single line chart. 
http://www.kometschuh.de/GoogleChartToolswithJSON.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the example and documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart), you need to create the data portion of the charts like so:

```
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);
```

`['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses']` is `[x-axis, line 1, line 2, ... lineX]`

then each subsequent array is the corresponding data.

In the example you've linked it shows the data as ['day', 'counts'], which corresponds to the above format.

You can see a representation of this right under the heading of `Data Format` [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

Comment: Chase, thanks for your answer. But how can I split my sql data like that. Other thing is that, date property should be updated according to the product. Different products have different sales dates... So have u any idea.

Comment: How do you currently have the data constructed? You would essentially take each row of data and push each array (row) into another array. This array of arrays would be the format for the google charts. Dates are a different beast. You'll most likely need to convert them to UTC time and then use javascript on the front end to convert them back to date strings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply chase. I know my question is also a bit unclear. Anyway I could manage it. Thanks for your reply.