# creating line chart using json and mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, json, linechart

Am creating a line chart using data from database,but i only get one single line as count vs date.
I want username as multiple lines.I searched lot for to get but cant able to solve my issue.In line chart i want date as x axis,count as y axis and multiple lines as username.Can anyone help me to get this.I encoded the data to json format.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"get_line_chart.php",
            type:'POST',
            success: function(output_string){ 

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'count');
    var json_data = $.parseJSON(output_string);
        var result = [];
    for(var i in json_data)
    result.push([i, json_data [i]]);
          data.addRows(result);
        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'',
                       'width':500,
                       'height':400};
        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var line= new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
               line.draw(data, options);
                } 
            }); 

      });
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
  </script>
```

mysql table structure

```
username   count    date
aaa         1       2014-05-07
aaa         1       2014-05-21
bbb         3       2014-05-01
bbb         4       2014-05-15
bbb         5       2014-05-14
ccc         7       2014-05-01
ccc         5       2014-05-09
```

Sample JSON data:

```
{
    "2014-05-07": 10,
    "2014-05-27": 2,
    "2014-05-28": 3,
    "2014-05-23": 3,
    "2014-05-30‌​": 2,
    "2014-05-09": 11,
    "2014-05-16": 5,
    "2014-05-26": 2,
    "2014-05-22": 2,
    "2014-05-05": 2,
    "‌​2014-05-06": 1,
    "2014-05-08": 5,
    "2014-05-12": 5,
    "2014-05-13": 3,
    "2014-05-14": 6,
    "2014-0‌​5-19": 2
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if we could see the value of `output_string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need the data from php, after getting the values, you need to prep it for google chart data format, so you really need to restructure it first. I'll just add a mockup query sample select since you didn't provide any database fetches. Consider this example:

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AsScYf)

**get_line_chart.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['get_chart'])) {
    // connect to database mysqli blah blah
    // sample select count, date from your table_name (this is just a sample!)
    // $query = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT count, date FROM table_name'); blah blah
    // while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    //     $result[] = $row; // blah
    // }
    $result = array(
        array('count' => 1, 'date' => '2014-05-07'),
        array('count' => 1, 'date' => '2014-05-21'),
        array('count' => 3, 'date' => '2014-05-01'),
        array('count' => 4, 'date' => '2014-05-15'),
        array('count' => 5, 'date' => '2014-05-14'),
        array('count' => 7, 'date' => '2014-05-01'),
        array('count' => 5, 'date' => '2014-05-09'),
    );

    // reformat the array and prep it for google chart
    // something like:
    // ['header1', 'header2'],
    // [-180, -300],
    // [-170, -50],
    // [-70, -30],
    // [150, 64],
    // [160, 256]

    $final = array();
    $headers = array_keys(reset($result));
    foreach($result as $key => $value) {
        $final[] = array(($value['date']), $value['count']);
    }

    // put the header and prepend it
    array_unshift($final, $headers);

    // output it
    echo json_encode($final);
    exit;
}

?>
```

**HTML/JS/jQuery**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(load_chart_data);

function load_chart_data() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_line_chart.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {get_chart: true},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(chart_values) {
            console.log(chart_values); // take a peek on the values (browser console)
            draw_chart(chart_values);
        }
    });
}

function draw_chart(chart_values) {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_values);
    var options = { 
        title: 'Your super chart!',
        vAxis: {title: 'count', titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        hAxis: {title: 'date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);    
}

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i want to create multiple line chart.username as the lines and count is the y axis,date is the x axis.i dont know how to arrange json format for 3 columns.I updated my php file pls check it.

Comment: @ammu i dont think you can put usernames inside the chart, i think it needs numerical values inside the data, [check out this example from google](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

Comment: @ammu try to fiddle with my answer above, check if its possible

Comment: so no possibilities for to get the usernames as lines in line chart.??

Comment: @ammu im nearly cracking it, just wait just a while

Comment: @ammu its possible to add the username, if i guess correctly? the usernames must be below right? (in the horizontal axis). [this is the hint i used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13159394/1978142)

Comment: username is the multiple lines,is that possible.Then only i will get datas with respect to user,you know any other plugins.Am searching for long to solve this.

Comment: @ammu yes i think so this can be refactored, instead of using `arrayToDataTable()` it is also possible to use `DataTable` instead, but its structure is tricky, regarding other jquery chart plugins, there is highcharts and morris too